# BehaviorSubject pairwise not seeing correct values in subscribe()

Tags: node.js, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have my behavior subject that I want to receive the current and previous value from.

`public connectedUsers$ = new BehaviorSubject<{ [socketId: string]: IUserInfo }>({});`

```
connectedUsers$.startWith(null)
.pairwise()
.subscribe((connectedUsers) => this.onConnectedUsersChanged(view, connectedUsers));
```

Then in another class i'm emitting the values.

```
this.connectedUsers$.next(this.connectedUsers);
```

The pattern is as follows.

```
connectedUsers = [null, {}];
this.connectedUsers$.next({_id: 'user1');
connectedUsers = [{}, {_id: 'user1'}];
this.connectedUsers$.next({});
```

This is the one that doesn't make any sense.

```
connectedUsers = [{}, {}];
```

When I would expect:

```
connectedUsers = [{_id: 'user1'}, {}];
```

Any idea why I would be seeing this behavior?

Comment: `[{}, {}]` isn't listed in your output, so I don't understand the question. Be aware that the behaviour subject will emit its initial  value of `{}` and that value will be emitted *after* the value passed to `startWith`.

Comment: Can you make a StackBlitz demo reproducing your problem?